# How to remove Primary Key constraint but keep Index

Tags: indexing, mariadb, primary-key

I am having a table with more than 100K records and this table is having primary key consisting 4 columns. Now i want to remove the primary key but keep indexes created by default due to primary key definition so that recreation of indexes should be avoided for such large value of data.

I am using MariaDB 5.5.x version.

Comment: You could try this - before dropping the primary key , create a index on the key column and then drop the primary key. It might take less time than dropping the PK and create a new index.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop the primary key, you cannot keep just the simple index part.

If the table is innodb, then you better drop the primary key first and then recreate the index because all [secondary indexes contain the primary key](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/innodb-primary-key-versus-secondary-index-interesting-lesson-explain) as well. So, if you create the secondary index first and then drop the pk, then mariadb has to modify the secondary index as well.

If you plan to create another pk, then create that first, then create any secondary indexes for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB, changing the PK (`PRIMARY KEY`) always necessitates rebuilding the entire table.  Period.

Make *all* changes in a single `ALTER TABLE`.  Here's what will happen (so you can see why this is best)...

1. Lock the table (to block any writes).
2. Create a new (empty) table with the same schema as the original.
3. Change the new table in *all* the ways indicated by the `ALTER TABLE`.
4. Copy all the data so the new table.  Note that it the PK is *changed*, this may involve rearranging the data.
5. Rebuild the secondary indexes.  (I don't know whether this is done as part of step 3, or as a separate pass(es).)
6. `RENAME` to move the new table in place of the old.  (This is atomic and fast.)
7. Unlock.

If you have two `ALTERs` to make the two changes to the PK, you would would be going through all those steps twice.

Every secondary key includes a copy of the PK columns.  So any change to the PK *requires* rebuilding *all* secondary keys.

In InnoDB is it *wrong* to have a table without a PK.  (A hidden serial number will be provided, but this makes maintenance, replication, etc, more painful.)

If you are talking about some Engine other than InnoDB, well, don't.  You should use only InnoDB.  (Much of what I said does not apply to MyISAM.)